# Como pegar todos os textContent dos <td> de uma tabela e atribuir a um array?

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo pegar todos os textContent das td que então dentro de uma tr de uma tabela. Porém, isso deve acontecer quando eu clicar na suas respectiva TR pai.

- Essas tr são geradas no PHP e retornada pelo AJAX e posteriormente inseridas no tbody da tabela do HTML.

**Segue abaixo** uma parte do código PHP de montagem das TR. (Só uma parte do foreach. tem criações de mais tds. Só coloquei uma para exemplificar):

```html
<?php

$tabela="";

foreach($lista_ativo as $value)
{

$tabela .= "<tr class='tr-row border'>";
$tabela .= "<td class='pl-3 p-3 td-descr'>$value[descricao]</td>";

$tabela .= "<td class='text-center td-mensal border'>" . number_format($value['m1'], 0, ',', '.') . "</td>";
$tabela .= "<td class='text-center td-mensal border'>" . $value['percent_m1'] . "%</td>";


?>
```

Como fica a tabela depois de montada **no HTML**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Agora eu gostaria de cada vez que eu clicar em uma TR dessa, eu pegasse cada textContent de todos os seus TD e atribuísse a um array.

Segue abaixo uma parte de como está ficando meu JavaScript, porém ainda não estou tendo êxito.

```js
liberarClickTr();

function liberarClickTr() {
  //Esse Array
  let valores_td = [];

  document.querySelectorAll(".tr-row").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      tr = e.target.closest("tr");
      console.log(tr);

    });
  });
}
```

- Segue abaixo o que sai daquele console.log (acho que já é um bom sinal).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Quando eu clico na TR já sai o elemento TR no console.log. Acredito que eu esteja quase no caminho certo.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Se clicar duas vezes na mesma linha irá adicionar textos duplicados na array.

Comment: Sim, mas eu zerarei o array antes disso.

Comment: Minha intenção é pegar esses textContent com o click na tr. Estou acostumado a fazer isso com jQuery, porém gostaria de fazer isso com JS Puro. Não sou muito fã desse addEventListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar outro forEach para pegar cada elemento e manipular da forma que desejar.

```
liberarClickTr();

function liberarClickTr() {

document.querySelectorAll(".tr-row").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      tr = e.target.closest("tr");
        let valores_td = [];
        this.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(e =>{   
            valores_td.push(e.textContent); 
        });

        console.log(valores_td);
      })

    });
};
```

Comment: Funcionou também, meu brothão. Só faltou jogar no Array, mas isso nós fazemos aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer que só os textos das colunas da linha clicada sejam incluídas na array, você deve declarar a array vazia dentro do evento `click`.

Já que as `tr` são os elementos que disparam o evento `click`, não precisa usar `e.target.closest("tr")`, basta apenas um `this`, que já referencia a `tr`, mesmo clicando dentro de uma `td`.

Aí basta você fazer um `.push()` com o `textContent` buscando todas as `td` da linha clicada. Para isso você usa `.querySelectorAll("td")` e faz um `for` para percorrer todas as colunas. Use também um `.trim()` para remover espaços nas bordas dos textos:

```js
liberarClickTr();
function liberarClickTr() {
   document.querySelectorAll(".tr-row").forEach(e => {
      e.addEventListener("click", function() {
         let valores_td = [];
         this.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(i => {
            valores_td.push(i.textContent.trim());
         });
         console.log(valores_td);
      });
   });
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr class="tr-row">
      <td>
         linha1 texto1
      </td>
      <td>
         linha1 texto2
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tr-row">
      <td>
         linha2 texto1
      </td>
      <td>
         linha2 texto2
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fala ai, Samzão. Me explica esse For ai.

Comment: Eu criei um lista de nós com todos os `td` da linha: `let tds = this.querySelectorAll("td");`... depois percorro essa lista com o `for...of`... o `let i` representa cada elemento da lista. Podia fazer um forEach tb: `tds.forEach(i => {`

Comment: A resposta do @Andrews também resolveria meu problema, não ? Mas você respondeu primeiro. HAHAHA

Comment: Tem que testar pra ver se funciona pra vc.

Comment: Testei as duas, a dele só está sem o Array.

Comment: E a resposta dele não trata do `.trim()` e outros detalhes, como o questão do `this`. :p